# Text alignment on top with multirow command

Tags: tables, multirow

```
\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \caption{Titel}
  \resizebox{.95\columnwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{p{4.5cm}p{10cm}p{3.5cm}}
        \hline
        Name & \multicolumn{2}{p{\textwidth-3\tabcolsep-\widthof{test}-2\fboxrule}}
            {long_title which goes over two coloums}\\
        \hline
        Explanation & \multicolumn{2}{p{\textwidth-3\tabcolsep-\widthof{test}-2\fboxrule}}
            {Explanation which goes over two coloums}\\
        \hline
    \multirow{3}{*}{Targets} 
                    & Target 1 is long text with two lines & not reached\\
        \cline{2-3}
        & Target 2 & reached\\
        \cline{2-3}
        & Target 3 & reached\\
        \hline

    \end{tabular}%
    }
  \label{tab:test}%
\end{table}%
```

I hope this photo helps to understand my problem:

[image]

I would like to align the text "Targets" on the top of the cell, like the second table.
I'm sure this must be simple to do, but I can't seem to put my finger on it.

Comment: Do i have to use something else than the "*" ?

Comment: This seems like the opposite of your problem, it may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1910478/centering-text-within-a-multirow-cell-in-latex

Comment: What if the reason of using multirow is you want top alignment, but also splitting over multiple rows.
Then you can't just leave multirow out of play, because then you get a white line in following columns next to the multiple lined text.
(Hope I am making myself a bit clear here)

Comment: It's super easy with a recent version of the `multirow` package. See MoonKnight's for the correct answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using `\multirow` (from the [`multirow` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow)) pushes the contents down to the middle of `3` rows. Instead just drop the use of `\multirow` to have the cell top-aligned:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx
%\usepackage{multirow}% http://ctan.org/pkg/multirow
\usepackage{calc}% http://ctan.org/pkg/calc
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[!ht]
  \centering
  \caption{Titel}
  \resizebox{.95\columnwidth}{!}{%
    \begin{tabular}{p{4.5cm}p{10cm}p{3.5cm}}
        \hline
        Name & \multicolumn{2}{p{\textwidth-3\tabcolsep-\widthof{test}-2\fboxrule}}
            {long title which goes over two columns}\\
        \hline
        Explanation & \multicolumn{2}{p{\textwidth-3\tabcolsep-\widthof{test}-2\fboxrule}}
            {Explanation which goes over two columns}\\
        \hline
        Targets % Don't use \multirow{4}{*}{Targets} here
            & Target 1 is long text with two lines exactly like this spans two lines & not reached\\
        \cline{2-3}
        & Target 2 & reached\\
        \cline{2-3}
        & Target 3 & reached\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}%
    }
  \label{tab:test}%
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The answer doesn't answer how to align to top in `\multirow`.

Comment: @chejnik: In this instance you can use `\multirow{3}{*}[\normalbaselineskip]{Targets}`, but the suggestion to do without it is far superior than fiddling with raising/lowering content in one column to match the other.

Comment: I see, thank you. I wanted to point out that it is only coincidence that the first column is smaller than the second one. In my case I had first column (`\multirow` column) much larger and need to align it on top.

Comment: @chejnik: True. There are other methods that one can use, including nesting a `tabular` inside a `tabular` and using the vertical alignment "anchor" point, or even using a `\parbox`. In this specific instance, it was easier to do it without `\multirow`.

Answer (score 38):

This is easily handled with the [newly updated multirow command](https://ctan.org/pkg/multirow). There is an option that specifies vertical text alignment; put **`[t]`** for top alignment.

In your example you would write:

```
\multirow[t]{3}{*}{Targets} & Target 1 is long text with two lines & not reached\\
```

Here is the code that should yield the desired output:

```
\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \caption{Title}
    \begin{tabular}{lll}
        \hline
        Name & \multicolumn{2}{l}{long title which goes over two columns}\\
        \hline
        Explanation & \multicolumn{2}{l}{Explanation which goes over two columns}\\
        \hline    
    \multirow[t]{3}{*}{Targets} & Target 1 is long text with two lines & not reached\\
        \cline{2-3}
        & Target 2 & reached\\
        \cline{2-3}
        & Target 3 & reached\\
        \hline
    \end{tabular}%
  \label{tab:test}%
\end{table}
```

[image]

**P.S**: Don't forget to add the multirow package.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Comment: When I use this when the multirow text (aka "Targets") has a larger font size than the rest of the table, it spills upwards, is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 6):

Instead of specifying the widths of the columns explicitly use the `l` specifier (which may require the array package). An example of its usage would be the following

```
\begin{center}
     \begin{tabular}{ | l | l | l | p{5cm} |}
     \hline
     Day & Min Temp & Max Temp & Summary \\ \hline
     Monday & 11C & 22C & A clear day with lots of sunshine.  
     However, the strong breeze will bring down the temperatures. \\ \hline
     Tuesday & 9C & 19C & Cloudy with rain, across many northern regions. Clear spells
     across most of Scotland and Northern Ireland,
     but rain reaching the far northwest. \\ \hline
     Wednesday & 10C & 21C & Rain will still linger for the morning.
     Conditions will improve by early afternoon and continue
     throughout the evening. \\
     \hline
     \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

this will provide an output like this

[image: Example]

Note the top alignment of all columns.

I hope this helps.

Comment: thank you for the try, but there is a reason why i have the widths

Comment: Since you did not change the example at all, it will be nice if you mention in your answer that you got the example from [wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Text_wrapping_in_tables) or some other place.

Answer (score 3):

I have been troubled with this alignment as well.
So, I end up with combination with fix-up parameter and filling vertical space
I use

```
\multirow{2}{*}[2em]{\vfil Target}
```

The `\vfill` will move the first character start on second row. And the `2em` move the base line to first row. You can adjust `2em` if too up/down.

Answer (score 3):

I have faced the same problem, since I have nested tables. I see someone else has beaten me to it, so I reiterate their answer verbatim –buth with emphasis on tables added– since none of the other solutions on this page work well when positioning tables within a multirow.

```
\multirow{2}{*}[2em]{\vfil <insert table here>}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format. This should be a comment to the answer by user2670906.

Answer (score 2):

this is an inelegant hack, and not automatic, but if you force the one-line "Targets" to occupy two lines, it should force that text to the top line:

```
\multirow{3}{*}{Targets\\ \phantom{.}} 
                & Target 1 is long text with two lines & not reached\\
    \cline{2-3}
```

Answer (score 2):

I will give a better solution with LaTeX3 package [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray). For multirow cells, there are `h` and `f` option for top and bottom alignment, respectively.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \caption{Title}
    \begin{tblr}{colspec={lll},hlines}
        Name & \SetCell[c=2]{l} long title which goes over two columns & \\
        Explanation & \SetCell[c=2]{l} Explanation which goes over two columns & \\ 
        \SetCell[r=3]{h} Targets & Target 1 is long text with two lines & not reached \\
            & Target 2 & reached \\
            & Target 3 & reached \\
    \end{tblr}%
  \label{tab:test}%
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's another hack:

```
\multirow{2}{*}{Target ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~}
% enough spaces to push Target to top
```

Comment: This seems to defeat the purpose; you're using a `\multirow` only to push the content up.

Answer (score 0):

Simply make 1 row: `\multirow{1}{*}{multilinetext}`

[image]

```
\begin{tabular}{cll}
\toprule
\multirow{4}{*}{\begin{tabular}{r}A\\B\end{tabular}}
& foo  & Lorem ipsum dolor sit    \\
& bar  & Maecenas sed purus       \\
& baz  & Nullam luctus id tellus  \\
& qux  & Aenean consequat commodo \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
~~~
\begin{tabular}{cll}
\toprule
\multirow{1}{*}{\begin{tabular}{r}A\\B\end{tabular}}
& foo  & Lorem ipsum dolor sit    \\
& bar  & Maecenas sed purus       \\
& baz  & Nullam luctus id tellus  \\
& qux  & Aenean consequat commodo \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
```